# 2d vectors c++ swapping rows/columns

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, swap

Just out curiosity, is it possible to swap rows/columns of a 2d vector with the STL swap_ranges function, like:

```
void swooop(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& ar2d) {
    swap_ranges(ar2d.begin()->begin(), ar2d.begin()->end(), (ar2d.end()-1)->begin());
}
```

Comment: you mean transpose a matrix?

Comment: @bolov no, I just want to swap specific rows

Comment: then yes, your code will swap first and last row. Swapping columns is another story though. You would need some sort of range adaptor to create a range that iterates over columns

Comment: @bolov oh, thanks, yeah that's what I meant, I mix the meaning of rows/columns often. thank you.